# Obtengo un error 400 una petición post en Django Api Rest

Tags: python, django, djangorestframework

Hola sucede que obtengo un error 400 donde indica que los campos nombre, latitud y longitud de un cliente están nulos.

Modelo cliente.py

```
class Cliente(models.Model):
"""Modelo para cliente"""
nombre = models.CharField(max_length=50)
latitud = models.CharField(max_length=50)
longitud = models.CharField(max_length=50)
empresa = models.ForeignKey(Empresa, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre

class Meta:
    ordering = ('nombre',)
```

Serializer.py

```
class ClienteSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = Cliente
    fields = ('id', 'nombre', 'latitud','longitud')
```

Views.py del modelo

```
class ClienteList(APIView):
"""
List all snippets, or create a new snippet.
"""
def get(self, request, format=None):
    cliente = Cliente.objects.all()
    serializer = ClienteSerializer(cliente, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)

def post(self, request, format=None):
    serializer = ClienteSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

La respuesta del json:

```
{
 "nombre": [
    "Este campo es requerido."
],
"latitud": [
    "Este campo es requerido."
],
"longitud": [
    "Este campo es requerido."
]
```

}

Cuando la petición POST usando el cliente de Postman envía lo siguiente

http://192.168.0.2:8000/cliente/?nombre=CC      Santafe&latitud=4.76220&longitud=-74.045379

Comment: Hola, ¿cómo estás haciendo la autenticación usando Postman? Imagino que tu API es para usuarios logueados.

Comment: @César pero por ahora no estoy creando ninguna restricción por Token o API ID

Comment: Yo lo que veo es que tu estás enviando los parámetros por la url, y no por el body de la petición como debería ser. Asegúrate que la petición sea de tipo POST y no GET, y luego asegúrate de enviar un JSON que contenga el nombre, la latitud, y la longitud

Comment: @GermanAlzate Estoy usando Postman y selecciono tipo POST le indico que voy a enviar x parametros y el los asigna de esa manera en la url, tienes un cliente API REST que recomiendes ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estas haciendo mal la solicitud. Cuando haces un get lo envias por estos parametros.

```
http://192.168.0.2:8000/cliente/?nombre=CCSantafe&latitud=4.76220&longitud=-74.045379
```

Si quieres hacer el post, debes ubicarte en la pestaña body del postman y enviarlo como comenta @German Alzete, en el request-body en un json.

Un ejemplo para ilustrar

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]